# Convert from types.JSON.TEXT to list of strings

Tags: json, string, go, text, trim

I have a JSON.TEXT (https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types#JSONText) that I need to convert to a list of strings. For instance, how do you convert

```
`["equals", "less than"]` // JSON.TEXT type
```

to

```
["equals", "less than"] // list of strings
```

I am trying to explicitly convert the JSON.TEXT type by using `string()`, trimming the `[` and `]` brackets, and joining them, but I am ending up with an array of strings with weird backslashes:

```
["\"equal to\"", " \"less than equal to\""]
```

Is there another way to achieve this, or how can I get rid of the backslashes?

Comment: You can do json unmarshal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the result of your trim/split it looks like the variable you have is

```
types.JSONText([]byte(`["equals", "less than"]`))
```

to convert it into a slice of string you can use the json.Unmarshal function

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types"
)

func main() {
    txt := types.JSONText([]byte(`["equals", "less than"]`))
    var slice []string
    json.Unmarshal(txt, &slice)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

here is a link to the playground : https://play.golang.com/p/cAiJjWNu8Vx

Comment: base string is `"[equals, less than]"` and your string is different your answer is not correct dude

Comment: @ttrasn looking at the result they had presented , i concluded that that the string used was `["equals", "less than"]`. I have mentioned the same in the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types"
    "strings"
)


func main() {
    a := types.JSONText([]byte(`"[equals, less than]"`))

    var s string
    json.Unmarshal(a, &s)
    trim := strings.Trim(s, "[ ]") // equals, less than (string)

    str := strings.Split(trim,",") // [equals  less than] (slice string)

    f, _ := json.Marshal(str) 
    fmt.Println(string(f)) // ["equals"," less than"] (string)
}
```

You need Unmarshal first, then trim [] character, then split string into slice and marshal string again